# Canvas tainted with CORS images

Tags: javascript, canvas, cross-domain, cors, pixastic

I'm having trouble using CORS-enabled images with canvas (Pixastic).

On server I have

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

in my htaccess file.

On client side I tried setting the crossorigin attribute in HTML, like so :

```
<img src="http://myseconddomain/image.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

without success.
 After that I tried in Pixastic's code :

```
var el = elements[i];
el.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
```

Does not work either.

I also disabled chrome's cache, but it doesn't help.

Chrome is logging :

```
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 
Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

even if HTML looks fine (`crossorigin` attribute is set), image headers look fine (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`)...
I don't know what to try next, so any advice is welcome !

Unfortunately I can't provide any link since this app is far from production as you can guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way, I'll post it here so hopefully it'll help someone someday.

It happened I wasn't messing with the right function in Pixastic's code, as the init() function is not always called as I first thought.

I added the following line in the Pixastic.process() function :

```
dataImg.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
```

And it did the trick.